# NodeJS : HTTP response fired twice

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm beginning with Node JS, and currently doing Learnyounode tutorial.

I'm into the HTTP moudle first step : **getting content through http.get() request**.

So I made a very basic thing :

```
var http = require('http')


http.get('http://www.vinylzilla.com/search/autocomplete?q=kiss', function(response){
    response.on('data',function(data){
        console.log("log: ", String(data))
    })
})
```

This should return something like :

```
log:[  
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/s-kiss\/533da2a069afa340368bb340",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/533da2a069afa340368bb340\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"S. Kiss"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/\/533da7d669afa340368d4344",
      "image":"    <img src=\"\/img\/artist\/533da7d669afa340368d4344\/mini.jpg\" \/>\n",
      "name":null
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/kiss-that\/533da92869afa340368dad5a",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/533da92869afa340368dad5a\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Kiss That"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/killer-s-kiss\/533dbef069afa3545d8d6b4d",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/533dbef069afa3545d8d6b4d\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Killer's Kiss"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/deep-kiss\/5341a80169afa34f7a8c259b",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/5341a80169afa34f7a8c259b\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Deep Kiss"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/lajos-kiss\/534f90f369afa38f448c492b",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/534f90f369afa38f448c492b\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Lajos Kiss"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/kiss-dezso\/535e809c69afa3ce3d8bce90",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/535e809c69afa3ce3d8bce90\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Kiss Dezs\u0151"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/kiss-kiss-king-kong\/536a21f469afa31c468c96b8",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/536a21f469afa31c468c96b8\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Kiss Kiss King Kong"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/andy-kiss\/536a289369afa31c468d3822",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/536a289369afa31c468d3822\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Andy Kiss"
   },
   {  
      "type":"artist",
      "url":"\/artist\/kiss-kiss-karate-passion\/536a58ef69afa31c46923f8b",
      "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/536a58ef69afa31c46923f8b\/mini\" \/>\n    ",
      "name":"Kiss Kiss Karate Passion"
   }
]
```

Instead of this I'm getting :

```
log:  [{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/s-kiss\/533da2a069afa340368bb340","image":"        

    <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/533da2a069afa340368bb340\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"S. Kiss"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/\/533da7d669afa340368d4344","image":"    <img src=\"\/img\/artist\/533da7d669afa340368d4344\/mini.jpg\" \/>\n","name":null},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/kiss-that\/533da92869afa340368dad5a","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/533da92869afa340368dad5a\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Kiss That"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/killer-s-kiss\/533dbef069afa3545d8d6b4d","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/533dbef069afa3545d8d6b4d\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Killer's Kiss"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/deep-kiss\/5341a80169afa34f7a8c259b","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/5341a80169afa34f7a8c259b\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Deep Kiss"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/lajos-kiss\/534f90f369afa38f448c492b",
log:  "image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/534f90f369afa38f448c492b\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Lajos Kiss"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/kiss-dezso\/535e809c69afa3ce3d8bce90","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/535e809c69afa3ce3d8bce90\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Kiss Dezs\u0151"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/kiss-kiss-king-kong\/536a21f469afa31c468c96b8","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/536a21f469afa31c468c96b8\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Kiss Kiss King Kong"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/andy-kiss\/536a289369afa31c468d3822","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/536a289369afa31c468d3822\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Andy Kiss"},{"type":"artist","url":"\/artist\/kiss-kiss-karate-passion\/536a58ef69afa31c46923f8b","image":"            <img src=\"\/image\/artist\/536a58ef69afa31c46923f8b\/mini\" \/>\n    ","name":"Kiss Kiss Karate Passion"}]
```

Note that console.log() is triggered twice with my response splitted into those logs : **why** ?

Comment: Can you describe in words what the problem is and format the second response so it's readable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "data" event does not guarantee that you will receive the entire message from the server in a single chunk. As pieces of the stream of data coming to your client are received, only those immediately available are handled by your function, in sequence. It may happen that the entire message arrives all at once, but the behavior isn't at all deterministic.

You can just merge the entire data into a single string, and then write it to the console.

```
var http = require('http')

http.get('http://www.vinylzilla.com/search/autocomplete?q=kiss', function(response){
    var content = '';
    response.on('data',function(data){
        content += String(data);
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Result: ", content);
    });
})
```

Comment: That was it, thank you a lot, I would never thought about this ! Do you have some docs on 'data' event ? Can't find anything...

Comment: @enguerranws That's because it's specific to the Stream API (the IncomingRequest obtained from a ClientRequest is a stream). See here: http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data