# Inserting a JSON variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

My code is below:

```
req.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(chunk.toString('utf8')));
    db.collection('collectionname').insert(chunk.toString('utf8'), function(err, result) {
         if (err) throw err;
         if (result) console.log("Added!");
    });
 });
```

The `console.log` prints the right message with JSON format, but this code can't insert the chunk in MongoDB.

So my question is how to insert JSON variable in MongoDB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't it? Any error messages?

Comment: Also, I would advise you to see this answer, as you seem to be making the same mistake. Data is received in chunks that might only make sense when merged. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26807694/1233251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` method of Mongo `collection` accepts either document or an array of documents, and you passing a string to it.

```
db.collection('collectionname').insert({
  chunk: chunk.toString('utf8')
}, function(err, result){
  //...
})
```